# natural transformations of simplicial sets

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

Let $\mathbf S$ be the category of simplicial sets, $X$ and $Y$ simplicial sets, $X_{\leq n}$ the restriction of $X$ to the full subcategory $\mathbf \Delta_{\leq n}$ of the simplex category.

There is a map

$Mor_{\mathbf S}(X,Y) \to Mor_{\mathbf S}(X_{\leq n},Y_{\leq n})$

given by the restriction of natural transformations $X \to Y$ to the simplices of $X$ of degree $\leq n$.

Under what conditions do we get an inverse to this map (when any map $X \to Y$ is fully specified by its values on the lower degree simplices)?

Comment: Do you the know the notions of (co)skeletality ? If $X$ is $n$-skeletal or $Y$ is $n$-coskeletal, this map is an isomorphism. Of course, for specific $X,Y$, it can be an isomorphism without either being (co)skeletal, but if fixing $X$ it is an iso for all $Y$, then $X$ is $n$-skeletal, and if fixing $Y$ it is an iso for all $X$ then $Y$ is $n$-coskeletal.